# Gnome Shell freezes when searching

Tags: gnome

I have my laptop running 11.10 and using Gnome-Shell for my sessions, however whenever I try to "search" for an application or file in the new gnome panel everything freezes and my CPU goes full load and I can't do anything.

Is this just a bug or is it hardware related to some certain CPUs?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/103072/why-crashes-the-gnome-shell-when-opening-menu-overview-windows-key-and-start-t/117770#117770

Answer (score 2):

In order to use 3.0 themes instead of 3.2 theme, just add theses few lines at the beginning of gnome-shell.css file in the gnome-shell theme folder :

```
.icon-grid {
    spacing: 36px;
    -shell-grid-item-size: 118px;
}

.contact-grid {
    spacing: 36px;
    -shell-grid-item-size: 272px; /* 2 * -shell-grid-item-size + spacing */
}

.icon-grid .overview-icon {
    icon-size: 96px;
}
```

You can now use search engine without freezes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the default theme or a 3.2 theme, 3.0 themes are not working and freezes when you search.

Comment: Just added those few lines of code to the css file. Heres to hoping it worked :)